# warnings.simplefilter("always") is not forcing warnings to be made in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, warnings

`warnings.simplefilter('always')` does not seem to cause warnings to be repeated in Python 2.7. It seems to have the same effect as `'once'`.

I am trying to test some code that issues warnings. Half of the time, the warning I am trying to test has already been issued, so my test uses `simplefilter()` to ensure that the warning is issued again. This problem only occurs in Python 2.7. [The other versions all seem to work as expected.](https://travis-ci.com/sandialabs/bientropy/builds/117383403)

I have followed the example in the Python 2.7 documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#testing-warnings
The example works as-is, but if I add a call to `fxn()` right before the test code, the warning is not raised and `len(w) = 0` instead of `1`.

Specifically,

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

fxn()

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    # Cause all warnings to always be triggered.
    warnings.simplefilter("always")
    # Trigger a warning.
    fxn()
    # Verify some things
    assert len(w) == 1
    assert issubclass(w[-1].category, DeprecationWarning)
    assert "deprecated" in str(w[-1].message)
```

Expected result is to run to the end with no output.
Actual result in Python 2.7.14 and 2.7.15:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "warntest.py", line 14, in <module>
    assert len(w) == 1
AssertionError
```

**Update**:
I also found that calling `warnings.resetwarnings()` after the first warning is issued does not work.

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

fxn()
warnings.resetwarnings()

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    # Cause all warnings to always be triggered.
    warnings.simplefilter("always")
    # Trigger a warning.
    fxn()
    # Verify some things
    assert len(w) == 1
    assert issubclass(w[-1].category, DeprecationWarning)
    assert "deprecated" in str(w[-1].message)

fxn()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "warntest.py", line 15, in <module>
    assert len(w) == 1
AssertionError
```

Comment: Hm, I wonder if the warning has already been marked "already given" before the call to `simplefilter`, thus blocking all subsequent warnings even after the `simplefilter` call.  I would consider it a bug, but that may be what's happening.

Comment: If I move the `warnings.simplefilter("always")` to the top of the snippet, then the warning is issued twice and the code completes without an exception. This might be a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a bug with Python 2.7, but I implemented a work-around based on Tom's recommendation. The workaround causes my unit tests to emit a ton of warnings for Python 2.7, but it passes. Basically, when the Python major version is 2, I added

```
warnings.simplefilter('always')
```

before the test begins, and I skip the individual

```
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
```

I had for in the tests that cause warnings that should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a situation where I can't control the filter before the warning might be raised the first time. What I needed to do for a workaround is smash the record of the warning having been raised. This is stored in `__warningregistry__` in the module where the warning was raised. The key is a tuple of (warning string, warning type, line number). If the value is truthy the warning will be skipped; if falsey or there is no such key, it'll be issued. In practice the warnings module never seems to set it to anything not truthy.

So if you're calling something in `module` that potentially raises a warning, the necessary steps are:

```
if sys.version_info[0:2] == (2,7) and hasattr(module, '__warningregistry__'):
    for k in module.__warningregistry__.keys():
        if k[0].startswith(
            'Expected warning string') \
            and k[1] is UserWarning:
                del module.__warningregistry__[k]
                    break
warnings.simplefilter('always')
```

I freely admit this is simply awful.